# Ruby string length "\\\'"

Tags: ruby, string

Why are `string.size` and `string.length` `2`? I think it should be `3`. If the first `\` is an escape character, then it should not be printed out. That is what happened to the third `\`.

```
string='\\\'' # => "\\'"
string.size   # => 2
string.length # => 2
```

Answer (score 6):

> If first `\` is escape character then it should not be printed out. That is what happened to 3rd `\`.

No, because what’s being printed is the result of [`String#inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-inspect), which escapes for a double-quoted string. Since a `'` does not need to be escaped here, no escape character (`\`) is needed.

> I think it should be 3

`size`/`length` doesn’t lie, so it is, of course, actually two.

In a single-quoted string, `\\` is the single character `\`, and `\'` is the single character `'`. So the resulting string is `\'`. `puts` is more useful than `inspect` since it does not show any escaping, just the literal contents:

```
puts '\\\''
# prints: \'
```

Comment: so the two "\" in "\\'" is first and third, 2nd "\" been escaped by first "\". correct ?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the answer :

```
string='\\\''
string.chars # => ["\\", "'"]
```

In this case you should use `String#chars` to see how many and what are the characters are used to compose the string.So the output of `string.chars` is telling the your string has 2 characters,thus the size is 2.You have 2 characters : one is `\` and the other is `'`. Both of them are escaped by `\`.

**EDIT(as @Andrew Marshall said)**

```
string='\\\''
string.each_char{ |char| puts char }
# >> \
# >> '
```

Comment: +1. Also, `string.chars.each { |char| puts char }` prints each char on its own line, sans often-confusing escaping.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Good idea to remove the confusion also.. :) I am going to edit my answer right now.